# Opencart 1.5.5.1 Checkout not working

Tags: javascript, opencart, checkout

I have an issue with a website where the Checkout is not working and even after searching these forums and google I cannot find out what the issue is. I was just trying to place a test order as I have done previously and as far as I am aware I have not made any changes which should affect the functionality since I placed the other orders.

I have changed the theme so it is not a theme issue.

There is also an error message on javascript console on chrome.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Can someone please help and advise how to fix this problem? URL is http://gpwholesale.co.uk.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: other than an undefined Google_checkout variable i am not getting any other errors, also i am able to proceed to checkout normally.

Comment: this is bcz you hv some js loading issue there not getting loaded properly

Comment: Here, checkout page process is working fine. Here, just, You need to fixed undefined Google_checkout variable error in Shopping Cart page.

Answer (score 1):

**For fixed error** undefined Google_checkout variable .

Go to your source > catalog > view > theme > asiancart-5 > template > checkout > & then Open cart .tpl file.

**Find and Remove below code :**

```
<?php echo $google_checkout; ?>
```